# Retorno de Dados de Uma API

Tags: php

Estou fazendo integração com um sistema de E-mail Marketing. 
Os retornos dos dados estão vindo no padrão:

```
Array(
[0] => Criaenvio\Grupo Object
    (
        [nome] => Geral
        [ativo] => 1
        [contatos_ativos] => 0
        [id] => JCp
        [_tipoSolicitacao:protected] => 1
        [_caminho:protected] => 
        [_parametros:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_parametrosURL:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Criaenvio\Grupo Object
    (
        [nome] => Lista Teste
        [ativo] => 1
        [contatos_ativos] => 0
        [id] => JCG
        [_tipoSolicitacao:protected] => 1
        [_caminho:protected] => 
        [_parametros:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_parametrosURL:protected] => Array
            (
            )
    )
)
```

O  resultado está sendo apresentado sempre em grupos de 2 com a mesma estrutura.
Não estou conseguindo acessar os dados apresentados. Preciso acessar o nome por exemplo. Tentei varias formas como `$dados[0]['nome']` e não consigo acessar os valores dos dados.

Preciso colocar esses dados em um `<select>`.

Comment: experimente assim: `$dados[0]->nome`

Comment: @DanielOmine Obrigado! Já tinha tentado como objeto também antes, mas não retorna/imprime nada.

Comment: @lelopes coloque as informações antes de chegar nesse array!

Comment: @DanielOmine. a resposta para requisição feita para API é o código acima na pergunta. Dei um var_dump e apresentou a resposta.

Comment: isso que apresentou é provavelmente resultado de um `var_dump()`. É usado para testes somente. Remova o `var_dump()` e trate o retorno da API normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer como o @Daniel Omine sugeriu. `$dados[0]->nome`.

Aparentemente você tem um array de objetos e no PHP array você acessa desta maneira: `$var["chave"]` e objeto você acessa assim: `$obj->atributo`.

Comment: não deu certo. Já tinha tentado isso antes. esqueci de colocar na pergunta.

Comment: Manda um var_dump do seu array e a forma como você está iterando sobre ele.

Comment: O resultado acima já é um var_dump é o resultado da resposta da API

Comment: a API deve retornar isso como JSON correto? Como você converte pra array? Consegue disponibilizar a API ou o JSON de retorno?

Comment: achei o erro pessoal, tava sobrescrevendo variável. Muito o brigado Anderson e Virgilio.

Comment: Disponha @lelopes :)